# Change individual button state

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following which uses clicks and jquery fade to display a div when a button is clicked and then change the state of the button....

http://jsfiddle.net/ttj9J/5/

**HTML**

```
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vi1KLp9.png"></a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png"></a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png"></a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content4"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png"></a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content5"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png"></a>

<div class="content-container">
    <div id="content1">This is the test content for part 1</div>
    <div id="content2">This is the test content for part 2</div>
    <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
    <div id="content4">This is the test content for part 4</div>
    <div id="content5">This is the test content for part 5</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
.content-container div {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
      $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
      $(".link img").attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png");
      $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/vi1KLp9.png");
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".link")[0].click(); 
});
```

This all works great but what I am trying to do is have a different button / pressed button image for each of the five buttons.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a background-image instead of a image. Then you can add a `.active` class and define the background-image via css for all your buttons like:

```
.link[data-rel="content3"] .active {
   background-image: url(....);
}
```

**Edit:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ttj9J/23/

Now you can add the classes as I described above

Comment: I had though about doing things this way instead.  Do you have an example or a link to one so I can read up?

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ttj9J/7/)

```
function handler1() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/vi1KLp9.png");
    $(this).one("click", handler2);
}

function handler2() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png");
    $(this).one("click", handler1);
}
$(".link").one("click", handler1);
```

[**Another DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ttj9J/9/) --> CSS approach through class

removed `img` tag used only `a` tags

**html**

```
<a class="link active" href="#" data-rel="content1"></a>

<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2"></a>

<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3"></a>

<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content4"></a>

<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content5"></a>
```

**css**

```
.link {
    content:url("http://i.imgur.com/vi1KLp9.png");

}
.active {
    content:url("http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png");
}
```

**js**

```
$(".link").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

after OP's comment

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ttj9J/21/)

**js**

```
 $(".link").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
     $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
     $('.link').removeClass('active');
     $(this).toggleClass('active');
 });

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".link")[0].click();
 });
```

**css**

```
.link {
    content:url("http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png");
}
.active {
    content:url("http://i.imgur.com/vi1KLp9.png");
}
```

Comment: How does this interact with the other buttons though?  In my original example when one button became active the other button became inactive

Comment: Sorry, you have just left me even more confused than when I started.  In my original version only one button can be active at one time.  In your version all of the buttons have individual states

Comment: I now have this version but it still allows more than one button to be active http://jsfiddle.net/ttj9J/10/